# Google APIs Ruby Client (gem) Error `uninitialized constant Google::APIClient::UploadIO`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

This has certainly had me baffled for a couple hours.  I've [bootstrapped my application as detailed by Baugues](http://gregandrachel.baugues.com/google-calendar-api-oauth2-and-ruby-on-rails) to the point that authentication via OAuth2 works and I'm just testing things out in the `session#create` (callback) action.  Here's some code:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    @token = @auth["credentials"]["token"]
    client = Google::APIClient.new
    client.authorization.access_token = @token
    service = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v1')

    file_content = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new("foo", "text/plain")

    # @result = client.execute(
    #   :api_method => service.files.get,
    #   :parameters => { 'id' => 1 },
    #   :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
  end
end
```

Upon authenticating, the above logic is executed in the `callback` method - which for the purpose of this crude test renders out `create.html.erb`.  I've commented out the `@result` instance variable that's just echoed out into the view.

However, `Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new("foo", "text/plain")` triggers `uninitialized constant Google::APIClient::UploadIO` when it clearly should not.  I've dug through the source of this gem and the `UploadIO` class is `required` in `media.rb` of the gem.

Advice and assistance appreciated!

#### Ref:

- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/
- https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/insert
- https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/ruby#saving_new_files

Answer (score 8):

Check your Gemfile.lock to see which version of google-api-client it is actually using. When I went through the same steps, it looks like it settled on 0.3.0 by default, likely due to google-omniauth-plugin being a little behind with its dependency. 0.3.0 doesn't have media support in it.

Trying changing your Gemfile to

```
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.4.3', :require => 'google/api_client'
```

and rerun 'bundle install' to force it to use the more recent version.

Comment: I have 'google-api-client' version (0.8.6) and it still occurs.

Answer (score 3):

For people who stumble across this whose `google-api-client` gem version is greater than or equal to 0.9 you will want to use something like:

```
gem 'google-api-client', :require => 'google/apis/analytics_v3'
```

Exchanging "analytics_v3" with the generated google service api that you are using.

For a complete list of generated API names, see: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/tree/master/generated/google/apis

Answer (score 3):

Here you can see how to migrate from version 0.8.* to 0.9.*

In 0.8.x the library would "discover" APIs on the fly, introducing additional network calls and instability. That has been fixed in 0.9.

To get the drive client in 0.8.x required this:

```
require 'google/api_client'

client = Google::APIClient.new
drive = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')
```

In 0.9 the same thing can be accomplished like this:

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'

drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2::DriveService.new
```

All APIs are immediately accessible without requiring additional network calls or runtime code generation.

**API methods**

The calling style for API methods has changed. In 0.8.x all calls were via a generic execute method. In 0.9 the generated services have fully defined method signatures for all available methods.

To get a file using the Google Drive API in 0.8.x required this:

```
file = client.execute(:api_method => drive.file.get, :parameters => { 'id' => 'abc123' })
```

In 0.9 the same thing can be accomplished like this:

```
file = drive.get_file('abc123')
```

Full API definitions including available methods, parameters, and data classes can be found in the generated directory.

[LINK](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md)